# Extend VB.NET Class Definition Across Multiple Files

Tags: vb.net

In order to organize various methods of my MainForm class, I would like to categorize them into several files.  Of course, the methods would still need to access form elements and additional variables I added in the MainForm class.

What is the standard / best-practices way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done using [Partial Classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_class#Simple_example_in_VB.NET).

An alternative way to structure code *within* the file are [Regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd032a17.aspx).

Of course, if your class code is so large that it needs to be split into multiple files you might want to consider refactoring it into multiple classes.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should look into using [partial classes](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22603)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer would be to use partial classes.  This isn't really telling you about best practice design for your application.

I'd recommend reading **Microsoft .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise**
[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-NET-Architecting-Applications-PRO-Developer/dp/073562609X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X)

You can download the source code that goes with the book from codeplex.  Just search for nsk.

The source code makes a lot more sense after reading the book.